# What happened when I installed graphic drivers?

Tags: 12.04

My laptop  is Dell Inspiron N5420.

I have tried to install NVDIA VGA driver and Intel graphic driver.

But I can't see anything about my graphic card in  "computer details".

I'm newbie so I don't know anything.

Comment: The URLs you posted didn't lead anywhere. What did you want to show/tell us?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Find out if its installed? or what graphics card you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check to see if the driver is installed go to the terminal and type lshw to see the drivers installed your pc.